# SQLServer Select Query Performance issue

Tags: sql, performance, select, sql-server-2008-r2, select-query

I have a performance issue with a select query. The query can take more than 4 minutes which is too long. 
This query is launched on .Net Client Process but not on Microsoft SQLServer Management Studio. So It can make sometimes 5 seconds and can make sometimes 4 minutes, 1 minutes, 30seconds.
So I have 3 questions:

1. Why this select query is too long? Because it can make less than 5 seconds with sqlserver cache free. I test this query with instructions DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
2. Why a sqlserver system   SQLTransaction named sort_init to rebuild indexes makes about 30seconds? How can I proceed to reduce this time?
3. Why on the execution plan, I have Clustered Index Scan, and not Clustered Index Seek (scan all page maybe takes  long time) . Each Clustered Index scanned is the Primary Key of each table.
   NB: I have another lot of queries using these tables which have Clustered Index Seek on join clause.
   What I'm doing wrong? How could I get the query to run faster? How can I optimize the index?

I use SQL Profiler to trace the issue, so I have these principal Events:

> A) SQL Profiler:

- SP:StmtCompleted:

TextData:

```
`SELECT [DespatchNote].[Id], [DespatchNote].[RealType], [DespatchNote].[DbOwner], [DespatchNote].[Archived], [CreatedOn], [CreatedById], [UpdatedOn], [UpdatedById], [KeyingFinished], [IsValidated], [ValidatedOn], [ValidatedById], [Notes], [DefaultDisplayLanguageId], [ReferencedTransactionId], [TransactionNumber], [IsCanceled], [CanceledOn], [CanceledById], [TransactionType], [IsPending], [IsGenerated], [PrintCount], [LastPrintDate], [AttachedFile], [IsPointOfSalesTransaction], [IsAffiliatedTransaction], [IsDone], [DoneById], [DoneOn], [IsSent], [SentOn] FROM [DespatchNote] INNER JOIN [Flow] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Flow].[Id] INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Transaction].[Id] INNER JOIN [ProductsMovements] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [ProductsMovements].[Id] WHERE (([DespatchNote].[RealType] = @param42485) AND (([ProductsMovements].[IsDone] = @param42486) AND ([DespatchNote].[Archived] IS NULL)))`
```

- Duration (ms)

  : 201277
- SQLTransaction :

ObjectName :    sort_init
Duration (ms):  29982
EventSubClass: 1-Commit

> B)Query with SHOWPLAN_ALL On

```
SELECT [DespatchNote].[Id], [DespatchNote].[RealType], [DespatchNote].[DbOwner], [DespatchNote].[Archived],   [CreatedOn], [CreatedById], [UpdatedOn], [UpdatedById], [KeyingFinished], [IsValidated], [ValidatedOn],    [ValidatedById], [Notes], [DefaultDisplayLanguageId], [ReferencedTransactionId], [TransactionNumber],    [IsCanceled], [CanceledOn], [CanceledById], [TransactionType], [IsPending], [IsGenerated],    [PrintCount], [LastPrintDate], [AttachedFile], [IsPointOfSalesTransaction], [IsAffiliatedTransaction],    [IsDone], [DoneById], [DoneOn], [IsSent], [SentOn]    FROM [DespatchNote]     INNER JOIN [Flow] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Flow].[Id]     INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Transaction].[Id]     INNER JOIN [ProductsMovements] ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [ProductsMovements].[Id]     WHERE (([DespatchNote].[RealType] = (select top 1 DespatchNote.RealType from DespatchNote))     AND (([ProductsMovements].[IsDone] = 1)      AND ([DespatchNote].[Archived] IS NULL)))
  |--Merge Join(Inner Join, MERGE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[Flow].[Id])=([x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id]), RESIDUAL:([x3distributor].[dbo].[Flow].[Id]=[x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id]))
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([x3distributor].[dbo].[Flow].[PK_Flow]), ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Merge Join(Inner Join, MERGE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id])=([x3distributor].[dbo].[Transaction].[Id]), RESIDUAL:([x3distributor].[dbo].[Transaction].[Id]=[x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id]))
            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[RealType]=[x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[RealType]))
            |    |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
            |    |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[IX3_DespatchNote_RealType]))
            |    |--Merge Join(Inner Join, MERGE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[Id])=([x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id]), RESIDUAL:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[Id]=[x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[Id]))
            |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[PK_DespatchNote]),  WHERE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[DespatchNote].[Archived] IS NULL) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[PK_ProductsMovements]),  WHERE:([x3distributor].[dbo].[ProductsMovements].[IsDone]=(1)) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([x3distributor].[dbo].[Transaction].[PK_Transaction]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

> C) For each table I launch DBCC SHOWCONTIG([MyTable]), so:

### DBCC SHOWCONTIG analyse la table 'Transaction'...

Table : 'Transaction' (770101784) ; index ID : 1, base de données ID : 5
Analyse du niveau TABLE effectuée.
- Pages analysées................................: 3690
- Extensions analysées..............................: 466
- Commutateurs d'extension..............................: 526
- Moyenne des pages par extension........................: 7.9
- Densité d'analyse [meilleure valeur:valeur réelle].......: 87.67% [462:527]
- Fragmentation d'analyse logique..................: 1.95%
- Fragmentation d'analyse d'extension...................: 5.79%
- Moyenne d'octets libres par page.....................: 631.1
- Densité de page moyenne (complète).....................: 92.20%

### DBCC SHOWCONTIG analyse la table 'DespatchNote'...

Table : 'DespatchNote' (1138103095) ; index ID : 1, base de données ID : 5
Analyse du niveau TABLE effectuée.
- Pages analysées................................: 409
- Extensions analysées..............................: 52
- Commutateurs d'extension..............................: 51
- Moyenne des pages par extension........................: 7.9
- Densité d'analyse [meilleure valeur:valeur réelle].......: 100.00% [52:52]
- Fragmentation d'analyse logique..................: 0.00%
- Fragmentation d'analyse d'extension...................: 5.77%
- Moyenne d'octets libres par page.....................: 806.2
- Densité de page moyenne (complète).....................: 90.04%

### DBCC SHOWCONTIG analyse la table 'ProductsMovements'...

Table : 'ProductsMovements' (1074102867) ; index ID : 1, base de données ID : 5
Analyse du niveau TABLE effectuée.
- Pages analysées................................: 1112
- Extensions analysées..............................: 139
- Commutateurs d'extension..............................: 138
- Moyenne des pages par extension........................: 8.0
- Densité d'analyse [meilleure valeur:valeur réelle].......: 100.00% [139:139]
- Fragmentation d'analyse logique..................: 0.00%
- Fragmentation d'analyse d'extension...................: 5.76%
- Moyenne d'octets libres par page.....................: 725.6
- Densité de page moyenne (complète).....................: 91.03%

### DBCC SHOWCONTIG analyse la table 'Flow'...

Table : 'Flow' (1890105774) ; index ID : 1, base de données ID : 5
Analyse du niveau TABLE effectuée.
- Pages analysées................................: 2662
- Extensions analysées..............................: 337
- Commutateurs d'extension..............................: 343
- Moyenne des pages par extension........................: 7.9
- Densité d'analyse [meilleure valeur:valeur réelle].......: 96.80% [333:344]
- Fragmentation d'analyse logique..................: 0.45%
- Fragmentation d'analyse d'extension...................: 5.93%
- Moyenne d'octets libres par page.....................: 579.2
- Densité de page moyenne (complète).....................: 92.84%

> D)Details for each table:

For all Table in my DataBase, each Index (Clustered and non clustered) have total Fragmentation less than 10 %.

### DESPATCHNOTE: (36360 LINES ON THIS TABLE) (7 COLUMNS)

   **Indexes** : PK_DespatchNote(Cluster)
IX3_DespatchNote_RealType(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_DespatchNote_Archived(non unique , non Cluster)
   Script to create the Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DespatchNote](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Archived] [datetime] NULL,
    [RealType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DbOwner] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [IsSent] [bit] NULL,
    [SentOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DespatchNote] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### TRANSACTION: (136120 LINES ON THIS TABLE) (20 COLUMNS)

   **Indexes** :   PK_Transaction(Cluster)
IX3_Transaction_RealType(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Transaction_ReferencedTransactionId(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Transaction_DefaultDisplayLanguageId(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Transaction_CanceledById(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Transaction_Archived(non unique , non Cluster)
   Script to create the Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Archived] [datetime] NULL,
    [RealType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DbOwner] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [DefaultDisplayLanguageId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ReferencedTransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TransactionNumber] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [IsCanceled] [bit] NULL,
    [CanceledOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [CanceledById] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TransactionType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsPending] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsGenerated] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PrintCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastPrintDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AttachedFile] [image] NULL,
    [IsPointOfSalesTransaction] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAffiliatedTransaction] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_TransactionType]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [TransactionType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_IsPending]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [IsPending]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsGenerated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_PrintCount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PrintCount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_IsPointOfSalesTransaction]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsPointOfSalesTransaction]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_IsAffiliatedTransaction]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsAffiliatedTransaction]
```

### FLOW: (136120 LINES ON THIS TABLE) (13 COLUMNS)

   **Indexes** :   PK_Flow(Cluster)
IX3_Flow_RealType (non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Flow_ValidatedById(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Flow_UpdatedById(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Flow_CreatedById(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_Flow_Archived(non unique , non Cluster)
   Script to create the Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Flow](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Archived] [datetime] NULL,
    [RealType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DbOwner] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedById] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedById] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [KeyingFinished] [bit] NULL,
    [IsValidated] [bit] NULL,
    [ValidatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidatedById] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Flow] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### PRODUCTSMOVEMENTS : (83631 LINES ON THIS TABLE) (8 COLUMNS)

   **Indexes** :   PK_ProductsMovements(Cluster)
IX3_ProductsMovements_RealType(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_ProductsMovements_DoneById(non unique , non Cluster)
FK_ProductsMovements_Archived(non unique , non Cluster)
   Script to create the Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductsMovements](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Archived] [datetime] NULL,
    [RealType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DbOwner] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [IsDone] [bit] NULL,
    [DoneById] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DoneOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductsMovements] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If you want more information please advise me
Best regards
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM [DespatchNote] INNER JOIN
     [Flow]
     ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Flow].[Id] INNER JOIN
     [Transaction]
     ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [Transaction].[Id] INNER JOIN
     [ProductsMovements]
     ON [DespatchNote].[Id] = [ProductsMovements].[Id]
WHERE [DespatchNote].[RealType] = @param42485 AND
      [ProductsMovements].[IsDone] = @param42486 AND
      [DespatchNote].[Archived] IS NULL
```

First, all your tables have `id` declared as the primary key.  Alas, the lowest hanging fruit is eaten.
i
Next, the question is about additional indexes.  My guess is that an index on `DespatchNote(RealType, Archived, id)` would help the query.  This should reduce the volume of data going into the joins, and might encourage the database engine to use the indexes for the joins.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have 2 Non-Clustered Index on columns DespatchNote.RealType and DespatchNote.Archived named : IX3_DespatchNote_RealType(non unique , non Cluster) FK_DespatchNote_Archived(non unique , non Cluster)

Comment: /****** Object:  Index [FK_DespatchNote_Archived]    Script Date: 03/17/2015 17:10:34 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FK_DespatchNote_Archived] ON [dbo].[DespatchNote] 
(
 [Archived] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: /****** Object:  Index [IX3_DespatchNote_RealType]    Script Date: 03/17/2015 17:13:53 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX3_DespatchNote_RealType] ON [dbo].[DespatchNote] 
(
 [RealType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: And I have A clustered Index on Primary key ID for each table like:       /****** Object:  Index [PK_DespatchNote]    Script Date: 03/17/2015 17:24:34 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DespatchNote] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_DespatchNote] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]